# Not exact result for PHP division

Tags: php, division, floating-accuracy

I saw a lot of strange behaviours handling float numbers, but I don't know why that one occurs and how to avoid it...

With PHP on Windows, dividing 1136 by 100 returns 11.359999999999999:

```
echo (1136 / 100); //11.359999999999999
```

Why is that?

Comment: I am running php on windows and get 11.36 as expected

Comment: What you mean with "What's the §ù$*?" ? Same result @mayersdesign